# JavaFX CSS styling of TextArea does not work

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm writing a simple JavaFX application, but I can't get some of the CSS styling to work.
The problem is the `-fx-background-color` property for my `TextArea`.

This is the relevant CSS:

```
.text-area {
  -fx-font-family: Consolas;
  -fx-highlight-fill: #00ff00;
  -fx-highlight-text-fill: #000000;
  -fx-text-fill: #00ff00;
  -fx-background-color: #000000;
}
```

All the fields perform as expected, except `-fx-background-color`, which apparently does nothing. I still have the default white background. As you can see in the picture, the `TextField` below, which has identical CSS, but does apply the background color as expected.

[Picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlQFO.png)

Any clues?

Comment: I think you may have the specificity issue here.Is this all of the css style that you are using on that page? check to see if the `-fx-background-color` is overridden by another rule. You can use something like firebug.

Answer (score 18):

You need to set the content:

```
  .text-area .content{
      -fx-background-color: black;
  }
```

...

Or see this answer maybe: [Transparent background of a textarea in JavaFX 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21936585/transparent-background-of-a-textarea-in-javafx-8)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem: What I did:

1. Created a .css file called console.css with following content:

   ```
    .text-area {
        -fx-font-family: Consolas;
        -fx-font-size: 15;
        -fx-text-fill: #ffffff;
        -fx-display-caret:true;
    }

    .text-area .content {
        -fx-background-color: #000000;
    }
   ```
2. On my scene called:

```
   scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass()
      .getResource("/stylesheets/console.css").toExternalForm());
```

Explanation:

- The second part just loads the css stuff. (trivial)
- The fist part (css): You have to check which property has to be applied on which part of the object. For instance: -fx-font-family is on .text-area but -fx-background-color is on .content. Understanding this concept let you understand all of the css stuff in JavaFx.
  [JavaFX-CSS-Docu](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea)
  (recommended).

Good programming :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use **-fx-control-inner-background** for example for a TextArea with id=textAreaField:

```
#textAreaField {
-fx-control-inner-background: #000000;
-fx-text-fill: #ffffff;}
```

and you can for more information, see this topic:
[Textarea javaFx Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423200/textarea-javafx-color)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using scene builder?

I tried the same css you use and everything works fine, maybe it's a bug in your version.

I tested it for text-area and text-field.

[image]

Comment: Did you check it is not overridden?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaFx ,TextArea has two substuctures (Content & scrollPane) ,for each structure has all properties of TextInputControl :

```
         text-area{ }
         text-area .content { }
         text-area.scroll-pane { }
```